# Is it possible to configure couchdb to generate ids other than the UUID way?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

Is it possible to configure couchdb to generate ids other than the UUID way ? 
I am using couchdb on a single node, I understand the downside of not using UUID for a distributed environment.

I need something like an auto increment or a shorter id. I have FK references 
like userIds : ["16011a5704ffe78e6de2afa4b3001d10", "55464a5704ffe78e6de2afa4b3001d10", ... ]
which can be too long if I use UUIDS..

Comment: Why not just create your own ID and use that instead? It defaults to UUID when the ID is empty.

Comment: My couchdb api is used by different services(projects) at the same time. so I dont have sth like an atomic check and set to find whether the particular id already exists in the db.

Comment: OK, so the answer is no. You'll need to either find a way to generate IDs as part of the application infrastructure, or accept the IDs that are generated.

Comment: And, honestly, it's not much of an API really if you're allowing clients/services to directly affect the DB.

Comment: client services call my api( which is a library say internalDBClient.jar) to talk to CouchDB...

Comment: So, fix your API to create an id.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide your IDs yourself, even the generated UUIDs are not NO-confilct guaranteed, it just minimizes chances of conflict but since you're concerned about the length, we can shorten it to like 16. First 4 determines the user, next 8 determine the timestamp and final 4 can be random.
Using [this](https://gist.github.com/bitsandbooks/2649444) multibase converter, you can use a char range of `0-9a-zA-Z`

1. Once a new user is using the system, he'll be allocated a unique alphanumeric of 4 chars (morethan 14million possible prefixes)
2. Next, we get the current time in millis and convert it using the multibase converter as provided above (should work for times upto year 8888)
3. The final 4 characters would be a randomly generated string just to pad.

It will be **very difficult** to break this. Depending on the kind of system you're building and the max number of users you're considering, you can cut this down to as little as 10 (3 prefix, 7 time) or even add more characters `(-_)` to your characterlist.

---

**EDIT**
This is my own implementation 
On my solution, every user already has a unique prefix once he's added by the admin, and there are not morethan 10 users created by the admin. Depending on the kind of data being created, a unique character is used as a prefix. Thenafter here's my method to convert current time base62. Finally, I append a random character.
`

```
base62 (val) {
  const SYMBOLS = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  let digs = ''
  while (val) {
    digs = SYMBOLS.charAt(val % SYMBOLS.length) + digs
    val /= SYMBOLS.length
    val = parseInt(val)
  }
  return digs
}
```

A single user cannot create two records under thesame category at once, and even if he does, it'll be rare to generate same random appended character.

Answer (score 0):

The reason UUIDs are used instead of simple auto-increment values is to reduce the likelihood of conflicts when multiple nodes are in use. CouchDB does have [3 different algorithms](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HttpGetUuids) in place that you can choose from for generating UUIDs.

If you desire some other id format, you are always able to define your own `_id` field, as the uuid generator is only called upon if `_id` is undefined.

Comment: All 3 algorithms produce 32 chars which wont solve my problem. I cant generate my own id as - My couchdb api is used by different services(projects) at the same time. so I donthave an atomic check and set to find whether the particular id already exists in the db.

Comment: You could just call an HTTP `HEAD` request against a document with the `_id` you are attempting to create. It is the fastest, least-overhead method for testing the existence of an `_id`.

Comment: Are you working with more than 1 node? Do you ever use replication?

Comment: I use just 1 node, no replication

Comment: can we do sth in the validate_doc_update to get auto increment ids ?

Comment: The problem wiht HEAD request is that i cant do an atomic get and set .. Different services are concurrently accessing the db

Comment: The only other idea I have is to generate the `_id` as a timestamp, a single number. Yeah, it won't be as short as an auto-increment value from 0, but it will be shorter than a 32-character uuid.

Comment: Also, what's the problem with a uuid anyways? Are you really expecting your users to memorize and use these `_id`s manually?

Comment: The problem with a long UUID was that one of my json document has a field which has FK references to other documents...  e.g. "userIds" : ["16011a5704ffe78e6de2afa4b3001d10", "55464a5704ffe78e6de2afa4b3001d10", ... ]

Comment: As a solution I converted the UUID string which is base-16 to base-36 string... Now I get a 13 char long string.
Yeah, not as short as auto-incremenet but lesser size anyways